# How to use scipy.stats.maxwell to find temperature?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, model-fitting, scipy.stats

I have speed data of many particles to which I want to fit the Maxwellian curve. I am trying to use the `fit` method from `scipy.stats.maxwell` to fit to my data and extract the temperature of the system from that.

From the documentation, I am unable to put my finger on what the parameters that we are trying to fit exactly are and hence how they relate to temperature.

Comment: Presumably they are in 3D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to `scale`.
You also likely want to set `floc=0` in `maxwell.fit(...)`

Cf the argument of the exponential: with non-zero scale it's `-x**2 / scale**2 / 2`, which you compare to the expected `mv**2 / 2kT`.

Comment: I think you mean `-x**2/(2*scale**2)` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.maxwell.html#scipy.stats.maxwell). In which case, T = (m/k)*scale**2.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Note that the factor of two is not squared.